# Colorbox doesn't look properly when i call it from click callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, colorbox

That's what i tried:

```
$('.color-box-link').click(
  function(){
   $.colorbox({html: '<p>tophat</p>'})
  }
)
```

And this code shows me broken dialog:

[image: Broken CBox]

But after resizing the window it shows the same dialog resized and repaired:
[image: Repaired CBox]

Additionally i see this in my console logs:

> Error: cboxElement missing settings object

On the other hand, when i execute this code from console:

```
$.colorbox({html: '<p>tophat</p>'})
```

I see perfect colorbox:

[image: Perfect CBox]

Whats wrong with it?
**jQuery 1.9.1

Colorbox 1.4.33**

Comment: i think it is css issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.color-box-link').click(
  $('.colorbox').text('tophat')
)
```

the safe solution unless you want to fiddle exact css , cause `<P></P>` is destroying your css